# Coding practice for blocks in python

Tags: python, coding-style

Is it a bad practice to write

```
num1=10
num2=10
if num2!=0: print(num1/num2)
else: print("Cannot divide by zero")
```

instead of

```
num1=10
num2=10
if(num2!=0):
    print(num1/num2)
else:
    print("Cannot divide by zero")
```

I personally prefer the former one. Any references for your view?

Comment: See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/, the go-to document for all things Python style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Per [the official style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it should be written:

```
num1 = 10 # note whitespace
num2 = 10
if num2 != 0:  # note absence of unnecessary parentheses
    print(num1/num2)
else:
    print("Cannot divide by zero")
```

The relevant quote for the specific thing I guess you're asking about:

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged.

However there are other style guides, and the most important thing is **consistency**.

Comment: Good one about the consistency!

Comment: It should not be used to have consistently bad style, though...

Comment: @GreenAsJade that is true, but I'd argue that consistently bad is better than an inconsistent mix of good and bad!

Comment: And this is the beginnings of why this kind of question isn't allowed on SO :D ;)

Answer (score 3):

You'd consult the [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out); the following entries are applicable:

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged.
>
> Yes:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah':
>     do_blah_thing()
> do_one()
> do_two()
> do_three()
> ```
>
> Rather not:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()
> do_one(); do_two(); do_three()
> ```

and

> While sometimes it's okay to put an if/for/while with a small body on
>   the same line, never do this for multi-clause statements. Also avoid
>   folding such long lines!
>
> Rather not:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()
> for x in lst: total += x
> while t < 10: t = delay()
> ```
>
> Definitely not:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()
> else: do_non_blah_thing()
>
> try: something()
> finally: cleanup()
>
> do_one(); do_two(); do_three(long, argument,
>                              list, like, this)
>
> if foo == 'blah': one(); two(); three()
> ```

You should also not use parentheses around the condition, and put whitespace around the operators.

In your case, in Python you'd also use exception handling rather than test (ask for forgiveness, rather than permission):

```
num1 = 10
num2 = 10
try:
    print(num1 / num2)
except ZeroDisionError:
    print("Cannot divide by zero")
```

Answer (score -3):

Preferably first option is recommended when there is a single statement after if/else clause. Again it really depends upon the coding style. First style is also used often for ternary kind operator / value manipulations. Link https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html would be useful for you.

Comment: All of the examples on the page you reference show the *second* option being used

Comment: Yes reference link gives various examples but without the braces () surrounded for if/else clause. Perhaps that's the big difference from best practice perspective if you look at your second option and the examples from the reference link - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html :)